# Blower motor running wide open after replacing resistor

Tags: honda, electrical, ac

After i replaced the resistor for the blower motor the fan runs continuously. It doesn’t respond to the fan control knob even to turn it off. Also now the the a/c compressor is not kicking on. Is it a faulty resistor or do i have something else going on?

2003 Honda accord 
Trim package unknown
4 cylinder 
4 door

The blower had just stopped blowing. After a little research I found out it is often the resistor that goes out on this model. So i purchased a new resistor 4 pin with heatsink.   Simply plugs into factory wiring harness I took the old one out and replaced it with the new one. The switch was off no power to the resistor. When i turned the ignition switch on the fan came on. But only on wide open. If I turn the fan selector switch to off the fan keeps running. 
The a/c is not turning on though. Just the blower motor. It acts like the control console has been bypassed and the blower motor has been hot-wired to on.

Comment: Have you shorted two terminals together on the board or a plug misconnected? That would be my first guess...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What happens if you put the old resistor back in place?

Comment: Purchase the resistor from Honda.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Nothing. The blower had stopped working. I did try putting it back in but the blower didn’t work at all just like before.

Comment: @SolarMike i don’t think so. There was no power to it when i put it in. Its just a quick release plug so without power going to it there shouldn’t have been any way to short it out. The plug is still in good condition so the terminals shouldn’t be crossing anywhere

Comment: @SethLindsey in the absence of detail, perhaps you were soldering a resistor to a pcb (a job I have done many times) and some peoples soldering efforts leave a lot to be desired...

Comment: Can you please tell us what year/model/trim Honda we're talking about? Can you please be very clear as to WHY you replaced the resistor and how you came to the conclusion it was that component that was the root cause?
Can please tell us where you purchased this resistor?
Can you be clear did you mount the new resistor in the blower case THEN plug it in and test it or just plug it in and lay it on the floor and try the blower (which will burn out a new resistor since there is no airflow across the resistor body)?